# toolstripmenu handle drop down

Tags: c#, winforms

I have toolstrip menu item with some other toolstrip menu items under it. How can i handle first toolstrip menu (parent) for not opening and showing children if some condition is met.

So i have:

```
Documents: (parent toolstrip item)
----Document1 (child)
----Document2 (child)
----DOcument3 (child)
```

and on `documentsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` i have

```
if(CurrentUser.HasPermission(0001))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You do not have permission to access this module!");
    //Here i need to prevent showing children of this parent
}
```

So to sum up, user need permission to press parent toolstrip menu item (documents) and when he press it and doesn't have premission i do not want to let him see what is under that parent (it's children).

I know i can make that toolstripmenu hidden or `enabled = false` but i have other things because of what it needs to be clickable.

Comment: Build the menu depending on the user's permission, then no further check is needed.

Comment: I wrote that i need to see there is button and i need to be allowed to click even if i do not have permission

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the DropDownOpening event:

```
void parentItem_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  allowedItem.Visible = true;
  notAllowedItem.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks you gave me idea. I will just set visible properties of not allowed items not where i set comment i need to put something. Thanks.